# Magento 2 How to remove Field required validation, if form Div is Hidden

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Magento 2 How to remove --data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}--  when div is hidden, I hide div when select box value is not equal to 0 using Script

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <form name="addData" method="post" id="addData" class="form" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <?php foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) { 
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
            //$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory'); 
            $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
            
            $product_ID = $product->getId();
            
            foreach($categories as $category){
                $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
                $cat_id = $cat->getId();
                //echo $cat_id;                 
                
            /* $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
                echo $category->getName(); */
            
            $customerId = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();
            //$product->getResource()->getAttribute('rx')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            //echo $product->getRx(); die();
            $is_rx = $product->getData('rx');
            
            if($is_rx != "" && $is_rx == '5479'){
            if($cat_id == '27' || $cat_id == '29' || $cat_id == '30' || $cat_id == '53'){  // change prescription option id here ?>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
            <fieldset class="fieldset col-sm-6">    
                <legend class="legend"><h3>Add Prescription: <?php echo $_item->getName(); ?></h3></legend>             
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                <div class="fields col-md-8">
                <?php
                    //$sql = $connection->select()->from(["tn" => $prescription_tbl]);
                $sql = "Select * FROM ". $prescription_tbl. " WHERE customer_id =". $customerId. " && product_id =". $product_ID;
                $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
                    
                    echo '<select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                    <option value="0">Please Select Option</option>';
                    
                    foreach ($result as $values) {
                        $name = $values['firstname'];
                        $id = addslashes($values['id']);
                        echo "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>'        
                    ?>
                </div>
                    
                    <div class="fields col-md-8" id="hidden_div">   
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="firstname"><span>First Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="firstname[]" id="firstname" title="F_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="lastname"><span>Last Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="lastname[]" id="lastname" title="L_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="allergies"><span>Allergies</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="allergies[]" id="allergies" title="Allergies" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="date_of_birth"><span>Date Of Birth</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="date_of_birth[]" title="DOB" id="datepicker" data-validate="{required:true}">  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="address"><span>Address</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="address[]" id="address" title="Address" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="phone_number"><span>Phone No.</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="phone_number[]" id="Phone" title="Phone" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="delivery_method"><span>Delivery Method</span></label>
                            <select name="delivery_method[]">
                            <option>---Select Method---</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 1">Delivery 1</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 2">Delivery 2</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 3">Delivery 3</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 4">Delivery 4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="display:none">             
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="product_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="product_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>"><?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="customer_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="customer_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $customerId; ?>"><?php echo $customerId; ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="fieldset col-sm-6">
                <legend class="legend"><h3>Add Doctor Details:</h3></legend>                
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                <div class="fields col-md-8">
                
                    <?php
                    //$sql = $connection->select()->from(["tn" => $doctor_tbl]);
                    $sql = "Select * FROM ". $doctor_tbl. " WHERE customer_id =". $customerId. " && product_id =". $product_ID;
                    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
                    
                    echo '<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
                    <option id="admOption" value="0">Please Select Option</option>';
                    
                    foreach ($result as $values) {
                        $name = $values['firstname'];
                        $id = addslashes($values['id']);
                        echo "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </div>
                    <div class="fields col-md-8" id="admDivCheck">
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="d_firstname"><span>First Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="d_firstname[]" id="d_firstname" title="DF_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="d_lastname"><span>Last Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="d_lastname[]" id="d_lastname" title="DL_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="hospital"><span>Hospital</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="hospital[]" id="hospital" title="Hospital" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="d_address"><span>Address</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="d_address[]" id="d_address" title="D_Address" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="specialization"><span>Specialization</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="specialization[]" id="specialization" title="Specialization" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </fieldset>             
            </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        <?php } 
        else if ($cat_id == '58') { // Veterinary Form?>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
            <fieldset class="fieldset col-sm-6">    
                <legend class="legend"><h3>Add Prescription: <?php echo $_item->getName(); ?></h3></legend>             
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                    <div class="fields col-md-8">
                    
                    <?php
                    //$sql = $connection->select()->from(["tn" => $veterinary_tbl]);
                    $sql = "Select * FROM ". $veterinary_tbl. " WHERE customer_id =". $customerId. " && product_id =". $product_ID;
                    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
                    
                    echo '<select id="getLname" onchange="SelectCheck(this);">
                    <option id="Option" value="0">Please Select Option</option>';
                    
                    foreach ($result as $values) {
                        $name = $values['firstname'];
                        $id = addslashes($values['id']);
                        echo "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>'        
                    ?>
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="fields col-md-8" id="DivCheck">
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="v_firstname"><span>Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="v_firstname[]" id="v_firstname" title="F_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="v_allergies"><span>Allergies</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="v_allergies[]" id="v_allergies" title="Allergies" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="v_date_of_birth"><span>Date Of Birth</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="date_of_birth[]" title="DOB" id="datepicker" data-validate="{required:true}">      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="breed"><span>Breed</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="breed[]" id="breed" title="Breed" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="v_address"><span>Address</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="v_address[]" id="v_address" title="Address" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="v_phone_number"><span>Phone No.</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="v_phone_number[]" id="v_Phone" title="Phone" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="v_delivery_method"><span>Delivery Method</span></label>
                            <select name="v_delivery_method[]">
                            <option>---Select Method---</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 1">Delivery 1</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 2">Delivery 2</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 3">Delivery 3</option>
                            <option value="Delivery 4">Delivery 4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset style="display:none">             
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="v_product_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="v_product_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>"><?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field required" style="display:none">
                    <label class="label" for="v_customer_id"><span></span></label>
                        <select name="v_customer_id[]">
                        <option value="<?php echo $customerId; ?>"><?php echo $customerId; ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="fieldset col-sm-6">
                <legend class="legend"><h3>Add Doctor Details:</h3></legend>
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                    <div class="fields col-md-8">
                    
                    <?php
                    //$sql = $connection->select()->from(["tn" => $doctor_tbl]);
                    $sql = "Select * FROM ". $doctor_tbl. " WHERE customer_id =". $customerId. " && product_id =". $product_ID;
                    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
                    
                    echo '<select id="getFname" onchange="selectCheck(this);">
                    <option id="dmOption"  value="0">Please Select Option</option>';
                    
                    foreach ($result as $values) {
                        $name = $values['firstname'];
                        $id = addslashes($values['id']);
                        echo "<option id='0' value='$id'>$name</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="fields col-md-8" id="dmDivCheck">                   
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="d_firstname"><span>First Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="d_firstname[]" id="d_firstname" title="DF_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="d_lastname"><span>Last Name</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="d_lastname[]" id="d_lastname" title="DL_Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="hospital"><span>Hospital</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <input name="hospital[]" id="hospital" title="Hospital" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="d_address"><span>Address</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="d_address[]" id="d_address" title="D_Address" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field required">
                            <label class="label" for="specialization"><span>Specialization</span></label>
                            <div class="control">                               
                                <input name="specialization[]" id="specialization" title="Specialization" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </fieldset>             
            </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>      
        
        
        <?php } } } } ?>
            
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="Save"><span>Save</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
        if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```